# Problema con consulta SQLite (Resultado No Esperado)

Tags: sqlite

Buenas quiero hacer un  delete mediante SQLite y me gustaría que la consulta no se ejecutara si el campo del where no existiese, ¿Esto es posible ?
A continuación os dejo un ejemplo de mi consulta:

`delete from SANCION_DETALLE where SANCION_DETALLE.SANCION = 47`

(Esta consulta se ejecuta aunque no exista la sanción 47 en mi tabla)

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás trabajando en Java, prueba a guardar los registros que encuentras en un array, y luego mete en la condición del WHERE solo los elementos de dicho array.
Prueba esto:

```
ArrayList<String> registrosEliminados = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
              query.append("DELETE FROM detalle ");
              query.append("WHERE sancion like '" + sancion + "';");

Statement st = conexion.createStatement();
if(st.executeUpdate(this.query.toString()) == 0) {
     System.out.println("---Sanción no existe o ha sido borrada---");
}else {
     this.registrosEliminados.add(sancion);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias he adaptado tu aporte a mi programa y funciona perfectamente.